# toHaveStyleRule cant find style defined by parent

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, emotion

I'm writing some tests for my component and have this test that works fine:

```
  test('should add padding', () => {
    const element = renderWithTheme(
      <List p={2}>
        <ListItem>1</ListItem>
        <ListItem>2</ListItem>
      </List>
    )
    expect(element).toHaveStyleRule('padding', theme.spacing(2))
  })
```

In my next testcase, I want to check styling on the children so I made this test:

```
  test('should add spacing to children', () => {
    const element = renderWithTheme(
      <List spacing={2}>
        <ListItem>1</ListItem>
        <ListItem>2</ListItem>
      </List>
    )
    element.childNodes.forEach((child) => {
      expect(child).toHaveStyleRule('padding', theme.spacing(2))
    })
  })
```

This test gives me the error `Property not found: padding`

If I edit the code to check for styling with getComputedStyle it works fine

```
const computedStyles = window.getComputedStyle(child)
expect(computedStyles.padding).toEqual(theme.spacing(2))
```

But I want all of the functionality that `toHaveStyleRule` offers, is there a way to make this work?

I think my main issue is that the parent component sets style, since it works when i apply style to the `ListItem` directly

```
const ListRoot = styled.ul<{ ownerState: Partial<ListProps> }>(
  ({ theme, ownerState: { columnSpacing, rowSpacing, spacing } }) => ({
    padding: 0,
    listStyle: 'none',
    '& li': {
       padding: theme.spacing(spacing),
       Some more style for the nested li
    },
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `target` specified in the [DOCS](https://emotion.sh/docs/@emotion/jest). I tested it before but didn't seem too work back then.
So I select the parent that has the style specified and add a `target: "selector"` to point to the specific style. It also works with media queries now

```
  test('should add spacing to children', () => {
    const element = renderWithTheme(
      <List spacing={2}>
        <ListItem>1</ListItem>
        <ListItem>2</ListItem>
      </List>
    )

    expect(element).toHaveStyleRule('padding', theme.spacing(2), {
      target: 'li',
      media: theme.breakpoint.up('md'),
    })
  })
```